# Retrieve Last Row from a table using Max or top or rowset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which contains 20 rows which has `Emp_Id` column value as

```
E001
E002
E003
E004
E005
E006
E007
E008
E009
E0010
E0011
E0012
E0013
.
.
```

But when I use

```
Select MAX(Emp_ID) 
from table name 
order by Emp_Id desc
```

Output:

```
E009
```

please give solution why I can't get last inserted row.

Datatype used for `Emp_Id` : `nvarchar(10)`

Comment: You probably should use numbers for IDs!

Comment: What **RDBMS** are you using? `mysql`? `postgresql`? `db2`? `oracle`? `sql-server`? Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Comment: You seem to have accidentally put a character value on what should be a numeric column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use MAX(MID(Emp_ID, 1)) in place of MAX(Emp_ID).

If it still does not work, converting string to number should help.
Example - MAX(TO_NUMBER(MID(Emp_ID, 1))).

Edit - 
First of all, there is no use for order by. And since you asked for SQL server, use this -

```
SELECT 'E00' + CAST (MAX (CONVERT (INT, RIGHT(Emp_ID, LEN(Emp_ID) - 1))) AS varchar) from Emp_Id;
```

Comment: Sorry sir both are not working hope you gave me solution for sql server

Comment: Try the edited part, I didn't know it was required for SQL server

Comment: I got the output sir but not in that format which is required i am getting '13' where i want  'E0013'.

Comment: According to your data, I guess you can append 'E00' to the result as the prefix always remains the same.

Comment: I've edited my answer to suit your needs. I hope this will help for sure.